# Conditionally sum in variable expression in total column

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm building a report in *iReport 5.0.4*, so far I have a *crosstab* table as follows

[image]

What I'm trying to do in Total 4 is having a total of sum3Measure but only of types "X" or "Y" (defined by the value in $V{col1}). I tried in *Text Field Expression* this:

```
$V{col1}.equals("X") ||  $V{col1}.equals("Y") ? $V{sum3Measure } : 0
```

but it returns always null. I did:

```
$V{col1}.equals("X") ? $V{sum3Measure } : 0
```

to test if the operator || is not valid but it returns null as well.

I used $V{row1} instead of $V{col1} to test it wasn't a problem different from the expression, it did the sum.

All measures are defined with *Calculation type Sum*

Is it possible to do what I want? if not, is there a workaround I can try?

Any help will be appreciated, if you need more info just let me know.